# Collision test to play a movie clip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I have a character that can move left and right and can jump. I have all this coded. I included two invisible buttons that I want, when the character runs into them, to play a movie clip. I tried to set up collision detector, but failed. I have been looking through tons of code, and can not find a solution that will help. What do I need to do in order for the mc to play when the character runs over the invisible button?

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? You get no event, when the Movieclips collide? You have no idea how to start the mc after the detection? Clarify please!

Comment: I have a guy (player_mc)....I have an invisible button (pressure plate). When he runs over/jumps onto the movie clip...I want a mc to play.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (invisiblebutton.hitTestObject(character)) {

   other_movieclip.play();
}
```

All of this should be running in your main game loop (ENTER_FRAME event handler)